# Seeking tool to generate topographic profile from points

Tags: dem, software-recommendations, elevation, profile

I'm trying to generate a topographic profile, but not the typical terrain profile. To do this, I generate a grid of points uniformly distributed on a surface of a DEM. From these points (from which I extracted for each one their respective heights and coordinates) I want to project the height of these points on an arbitrary line (created by me in a separate shapefile).

What tools should I use?

Answer (score -1):

I dont know what software you have access to, but isn't this tool what you are looking for https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/ready-to-use/profile.htm ?
".. output from this tool is polyline features with elevation values extracted along the input line features for each vertex"

Or this tool https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/profiletool/, which will "...plots profile lines from raster layers or point vector layer with elevation field. Supports multiple lines as well as graph export to svg, pdf, png or csv file. Supports 3D polyline export to dxf"

Comment: the tool that i am looking for is that https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/3d-analyst/using-the-point-profile-interactive-tool.htm

Comment: I have a dem, with different mapped surfaces. For each of them, I generate a regular grid of points. For every point, I obteined from dem, coordinates and elevation data. I want to create a profile, from a line, longitudinal to the surface (that represent the cross-section to the profile), projecting the height of each point. The result I'm looking for, is a profile with points with its corresponding height, distributed across the distance of the line.

Comment: thanks for answer me!